# Using "Aabaco Small Business" I want to Display all orders assigned to any of the customer's email addresses

Tags: php

I tried to get data using IMAP/POP3 but it is work only for yahoo mail,
isn't provide any functionality for Yahoo Small Business.
How can I get all order listing with provided customer credentials?

Comment: Just need help from which tool or api am able to get it.?
Thanks in Advance.